# Extra login to load api data

Tags: vue.js

I'm developing a simple web application with `VueJs`. The problem that arose is when I log in to the admin page, the section of ordered items is loaded but the data aren't **( i.e. it shows an empty table )** and when I logout and login again then only shows the table displaying the items. I thought it was an issue with clearing `localStorage` but it wasn't. I don't know if that's an API refreshing issue or error in my vue code. It's such a bizarre problem that every time **I need to login twice**. Any little suggestion would be thankful!

[ Code]

```
methods: {
    foodname: function () {
      this.order.forEach(thing => {
        this.foodItems.forEach(element => {
          if (element.id === thing.menu_item) {
            this.orderList.push({
              date: thing.date,
              user: thing.user,
              name: element.name
            })
          }
        })
      })
    },
computed: {
    order () {
      return this.$store.getters.order
    },
    foodItems: function () {
      return this.$store.getters.items
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getOrder')
    this.$store.dispatch('loadItems')
    this.$store.dispatch('loadSelectedItems')
    this.foodname()
  }
```

Here, `getOrder`, `loadItems` and `loadSelectedItems` are for get requests in three different api urls.

To display the items, I've done

```
<tr v-for="item in orderList" :key="item.index">
          <td>{{ item.user }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Also, out of the blue, does `this.$nextTick();` after loading your ordered items helps?

Comment: That didn't work sadly and I've just edited the question adding the code.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54759341/5995973

Comment: Agreed with the above comment, it looks like you need some `async` / `await` in your `mounted()`